# Behat reading default .env file and not .env.behat in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, behat

FeatureContext.php

```
/**
 * @Then I can do something with Laravel
 */
public function iCanDoSomethingWithLaravel()
{
    PHPUnit::assertEquals('.env.behat', app()->environmentFile());
    PHPUnit::assertEquals('acceptance', env('APP_ENV'));
}
```

Console output after running behat

Scenario: Dashboard is locked to guests

```
 And I can do something with Laravel # FeatureContext::iCanDoSomethingWithLaravel()
   Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
   --- Expected
   +++ Actual
   @@ @@
   -'acceptance'
   +'local'
```

behat.yml

```
default:
  extensions:
    Laracasts\Behat:
      env_path: .env.behat
    Laracasts\Behat\ServiceContainer\BehatExtension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension\ServiceContainer\MinkExtension:
      default_session: laravel
      laravel: ~
```

.env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```

.env.behat

```
APP_ENV=acceptance
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Laravel Homestead, the issue isn't with it reading the `.env` file, more that it is reading it from the default `APP_ENV` set in your `homestead.yaml` file. Take the `APP_ENV` variable out of your `homestead.yaml` file and then re-provision your homestead box and it should work fine.

These are the offending lines in your `homestead.yaml:`

```
- key: APP_ENV
  value: local
```

I have literally just encountered the same issue and this is what fixed it for me.

Comment: After reading this post, I just set APP_ENV in my Homestead.yaml as 'acceptance' for example and the tests ran OK

Comment: @victorf This isn't ideal, though, as you don't want to be changing the environment for your local environment every time you run your tests. I'm pretty sure you have to stop and start your Vagrant box to change the variable, and there are parts of your application that use the `APP_ENV` to determine how it should behave.